# How can I undo the Bool Tool?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have the bool tool addon installed. I use it mostly for the difference function, to cut one shape out of another. Once the shape is cut I might need to duplicate the object that made the cut and use it again. However, the object remains with the cage around it and I can see no way of restoring it to the original object.

How do I remove the bool tool from the cutting object?

In object properties there are 2 entries in custom properties: Btool Brush, and BtoolFtransform. I tried deleting those but it has no effect and the cage remains around the object regardless of what I do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bool Tool* will automatically change the display mode of the cutter object, to go back to its default mode, go into the *Object panel > Viewport Display > Display As >* switch to *Textured* for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The mystery is finally solved!!